# get class name for empty queryset in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have empty queryset of model *Student*

```
students = Students.objects.all()
```

If the above queryset is empty, then how can i get the model(class name)?

How can i get the model name for empty queryset?

EDIT:

How can i get the app name from the queryset?

Comment: "I have empty queryset of model Student" - not necessarily empty, but `Students.objects.none()` is an empty queryset all the time.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
>>> students = Students.objects.all()

# The queryset's model class:
>>> students.model
project.app.models.Student

# Name of the model class:
>>> students.model.__name__
'Student'

# Import path of the models module:
>>> students.model.__module__
'project.app.models'

# Django app name:
>>> students.model._meta.app_label
'app'
```

Comment: Thanks jkbr. How can i get the app name from queryset?

Comment: I hope this is documented...:/

Comment: I haven't find this anywhere in the documentation, is there a page that show QuerySet attributes?

Comment: @jakub-roztocil How would I get all student's names? If the model had a field called name.

Comment: @Mojimi `print(myqueryset.__dict__)` will help a little

Answer (score 9):

```
students.model
```

Querysets have a `model` attribute that can be used to retrieve the model they are associated with.

Comment: how can i do this in a template?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
students.model.__name__
>>> `Students`
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the model name from queryset

```
queryset.__dict__['model'].__name__
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a model type which is a string:

```
queryset.model.__name__
```

You can check the type:

```
type(queryset.model.__name__)
>>> str
```

And if you want `models.base.ModelBase` type:

```
queryset.model._meta.model
```

You can check the type:

```
type(queryset.model._meta.model)                                                                                                                                             
>>> django.db.models.base.ModelBase
```

Comment: For a nomalized lowercase output: 
`queryset.model._meta.model_name`