# Django Template: How to determine which object/model a queryset is composed of?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I’ve written a search function for my django app which does a number of different filtering depending on the search string entered in the search box. I save the result of these different query filtering in a variable called ‘results’ (seems appropriate), but I am having trouble getting the template to render the variable properly depending on the type of object the queryset is based on. The results variable can either take the form of a queryset of ‘filtered’ object1 or 0 results (if nothing of object1 matched that search) OR it can take the form of a queryset of 'filtered' object2 or 0 results (if nothing of object2 matched that search). Later this might become many more different objects/models understandably so I would like to know how to check what type of object the queryset is composed of.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a Django queryset, you can retrieve its model using the well named `model` attribute, that gives a `Model` object.

```
queryset = SomeModel.objects
print queryset.model  # prints 'path.to.your.app.models.SomeModel'
```

You probably do not want to check against the full path, so you can use `__name__`

```
print queryset.model.__name__  # prints 'SomeModel'
```

But since you cannot access underscore attributes in templates, you'll have to add this information in your view.

Update:
To check what is the model name in the template, you can add it on the queryset object:

```
queryset.model_name = queryset.model.__name__
```

Then in your template:

```
{% if queryset.model_name = 'SomeModel' %}
    ... do something
{% elif queryset.model_name = 'SomeOtherModel' %}   
    ....
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But you're saying basically there's no way to check in the template then right? I have to separate out my 'results' variable in my views then t different types of variables pertaining to each result then?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the update on your answer. This solved me lots of headaches.

Answer (score 1):

1) Checking for a zero
2) checking for the field ".**name**" of the first element of selection.
 also [get class name for empty queryset in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487690/get) - class - name - for - empty - queryset - in - django

If did not turn out, please code

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean by .name? Can I do resuls.name in my template?