# Django QuerySet class attributes

Tags: django, django-queryset

This question [get class name for empty queryset in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487690/get-class-name-for-empty-queryset-in-django) exemplifies that a `QuerySet` in Django has the attribute `model`

The [QuerySet API documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/) lists the methods, but I couldn't find a place where it lists its attributes

Is there a way to retrieve them, or I am missing where they are at the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not nice that it appears to be necessary, but there is a "source" link next to the line that says what the class definition looks like. That leads to its `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, model=None, query=None, using=None, hints=None):
    self.model = model
    self._db = using
    self._hints = hints or {}
    self.query = query or sql.Query(self.model)
    self._result_cache = None
    self._sticky_filter = False
    self._for_write = False
    self._prefetch_related_lookups = []
    self._prefetch_done = False
    self._known_related_objects = {}  # {rel_field, {pk: rel_obj}}
    self._iterable_class = ModelIterable
    self._fields = None
```

From this we can see that `self.model` and `self.query` exist, but all the others are private and you shouldn't use them.

From scrolling further, there's also the property, `queryset.db`, the database that would be used if the query were to run now.

Comment: By 'It's not nice" did you mean that the API should list the attributes or my question was just a lack of attention?

Comment: In accordance with Django's [API stability policy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/misc/api-stability/#api-stability), anything that is not documented is not part of the public API, and Django reserves the right to change the code in a backwards-incompatible way. Attributes such as `model` and `query` are an implementation detail, not a public API. While these two attributes have been around forever, and I doubt they will be changed in any breaking way, it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Mojimi: I mean ideally things like this would be documented and you wouldn't need to look at the code. But as knbk says, this isn't officially supported API.